# How to make an input box in VBS that is always open?

Tags: while-loop, vbscript

I'm writing a VBS program where there is a while loop, but it's not easily breakable because it's not seen in the task manager easily (Not enough time to find it in the background processes because of the program). So, my solution was to make a simple input box that is always open which allows you to break the loop by typing Q. But, I can't find a way to allow the code in front of the input box code to run without having an input in the input box (Yes, No, Cancel). Any help? I'm new to VBS.

Comment: Use the details tab. The process tab is for simple users. All programs are single threaded (usually) on the user interface. It a modal dialog so is blocking.

Comment: Please spend some more time on clarifying what it is you actually want to accomplish, as well as the code you tried and is giving you issues.

Comment: To answer your question is you can't with a `msgbox` or `inputbox`. The traditional VBScript way is to use an **HTA** which is a web page with embedded VBScript. But as you are using the wrong tab in Task Manager it's easier to use the right tab or to kill all VBScripts put in a shortcut `taskkill /im wscript.exe /f`.

Comment: Please edit your question and post your code !